# Importing vs Installing spark

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am new to the spark world and to some extent coding.

This question might seem too basic but please clear my confusion.

I know that we have to import spark libraries to write spark application. I use intellij and sbt.
After writing the application , I can also run them and see the output on "run".

My question is, why should I install spark separately on my machine(local) if I can just import them as libraries and run them.
Also what is the need for it to be installed on the cluster since we can just submit the jar file and jvm is already present in all the machines of the clustor

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your confusion.

Actually you don't really need to install spark on your machine if you are for example running it on `scala/java` and you can just import spark-core or any other dependancies into your project and once you start your spark job on mainClass it will create an standalone spark runner on your machine and run your job on if (`local[*]`).

There are many reasons for having spark on your local machine.

One of them is for running spark job on pyspark which requires spark/python/etc libraries and a runner(local[*] or remote[*]).

Another reason can be if you want to run your job on-premise.

It might be easier to create cluster on your local datacenter and maybe appoint your machine as master and the other machines connected to your master as worker.(this solution might be abit naive but you asked for basics so this might spark your curiosity to read more about infrastructure design of a data processing system more)